# Archlinux configure grapic driver lenovo z710

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, nvidia

I want to configure my graphic card driver on a lenovo z710, because my laptop is overheating. On Ubuntu I installed bumblebee and other stuff, but my system crashed, this time I want to avoid this.

my system: Intel 4th Generation Nvidea 840m

I would like to have a hybrid system and not just use my Intel grapic card and switch the nvidia off. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hybrid_graphics

Does anybody tried to do this and it is quite stable?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Bumblebee with proprietary nvidia driver for two years on Arch on ASUS Zenbook UX32VD without major problems. But the performance is not as good as on the Windows systems.

To prevent overheating just switch off the nvidia card on startup using bbswitch.

If you want to use both GPUs, the nvidia card must be switched manually on demand and the intel graphics is used as default.

To install bumblebee and bbswitch, follow this guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee.

Then, to run apps with nvidia card, use `$ optirun <your_app>` or alternatively with Primus installed: `$ vblank_mode=0 primusrun <your_app>` (the `vblank_mode=0` disables vsync to prevent input lag).

PRIME is also an alternative to Bumblebee using Nouveau open-source driver: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME. But I've never had good results with this technology.